# preg_match Named subpatterns - optional keys

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Now trying for hours but now I admit that I'm stuck.

I'm trying to match an url pattern for a simple framework.

```
$url = 'controller';
preg_match('/(?P<controller>\w+)/', $url, $matches);
```

This works for pages without a slash but i want to match urls like controller/action with optional keys

```
$url = 'controller/action';
preg_match('/(?P<controller>(?P<action>)?\w+)/', $url, $matches);
```

Here is the problem. I can't figure out how to make the 'action' key with a slash in front of it optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
preg_match('/(?P<controller>\w+)(?P<action>\/\w+)?/', $url, $matches);
```

You have to match the first part `(?P<controller>\w+)` at first and then close the capturing group. Then **after** this part your optional part starts `(?P<action>\/\w+)?` including the slash and again the `\w+`.

If you don't want the slash in the captured part, put a second group around that is optional and move the slash from the capturing group to the optional one:

```
preg_match('/(?P<controller>\w+)(?:\/(?P<action>\w+))?/', $url, $matches);
```

A group starting with `?:` is a non capturing group.

Comment: it works :) the action is matched as '/foo', is there a way to leave out the slash

Comment: THANK YOU ! This was so confusing. I would probably never got it on my own.